# CSRF Token coming empty in login form using Spring MVC and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

${_csrf.parameterName} and ${_csrf.token} coming empty in login form. I am using Spring 4.1.3 and Spring Security 3.2.5

All the configurations are made correctly but still i am getting

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

as

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, i placed the security filter tags in web.xml at top of any other filters and it worked.

Comment: i did the same, but still getting empty csrf

Comment: In spring security xml file, you need to have <intercept> tag for the respective uri, in which <csrf> tag must be there.

Comment: @Giridhar Please provide complete answer.

Comment: <http pattern="/some-uri-pattern/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless">
  <csrf disabled="false" />
 </http>